# I want to disable price range in product page and show the minimum amount on category and shop page in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have several product that use[Screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biVxw.png) variations on my website, I want to hide the price range in product page & show only the minimum amount everywhere else on the website, only the selected variation price should be shown on product page, please help

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved

Comment: A mere "I want" is not a question. If you want to get help here, then please go read [ask] first of all, and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
```

as a last resort hide the price with css:

```
.class {
display:none
}
```